# Split string text in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below string which needs splitting to allow for insert into a table.

The data is coming from:

http://smartgriddashboard.eirgrid.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=co2Intensity&region=NI&datefrom=30-Aug-2021%2000:00&dateto=30-Aug-2021%2023:59

I am developing a function to run on an agent job to read the data and then parse it into MSSQL DB. e.g.

```
DECLARE @fromTime NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @toTime NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @URL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

Set @fromTime = REPLACE(FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 'dd-MMM-yyyy 00:00' ), ' ','%20')
Set @toTime = REPLACE(FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE()), 'dd-MMM-yyyy 23:59' ), ' ','%20')

select @URL2 = 
concat('http://smartgriddashboard.eirgrid.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=co2Intensity&region=ALL&datefrom=',@fromTime,'&dateto=',@toTime)

DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = @URL2
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @currenttime as datetime;
set @currenttime = GETDATE()

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
   @URL,
   'False'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

IF((Select @ResponseText) <> '')
BEGIN
   DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (Select @ResponseText)
  
  --do something here to parce the return data
 ;with CTE(raw) as 
 (

 select replace(replace(replace(replace(@json,' ','-'),' ','-'),' ','-'),' ','-')
 )
 select * from CTE
     
 select @json

--write to SQL table.

END
ELSE
BEGIN
 DECLARE @ErroMsg NVARCHAR(30) = 'No data found.';
 Print @ErroMsg;
END
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

The delimitator for each line in the table is a double space. The delimitator for each column is a ','.

The first set of data before the fist double space delimitator is the column/table headings and is fixed. e.g.

```
DATE & TIME  |  CO2 INTENSITY (gCO2/kWh)  |  REGION
```

Example output from URL above

```
DATE & TIME, CO2 INTENSITY (gCO2/kWh), REGION  28 August 2021 00:00,470,All Island  28 August 2021 00:15,471,All Island  28 August 2021 00:30,471,All Island  28 August 2021 00:45,472,All Island  28 August 2021 01:00,470,All Island  28 August 2021 01:15,471,All Island  28 August 2021 01:30,468,All Island  28 August 2021 01:45,471,All Island  28 August 2021 02:00,468,All Island  28 August 2021 02:15,460,All Island  28 August 2021 02:30,452,All Island  28 August 2021 02:45,450,All Island  28 August 2021 03:00,464,All Island  28 August 2021 03:15,469,All Island  28 August 2021 03:30,472,All Island  28 August 2021 03:45,476,All Island  28 August 2021 04:00,472,All Island  28 August 2021 04:15,477,All Island  28 August 2021 04:30,488,All Island  28 August 2021 04:45,485,All Island  28 August 2021 05:00,488,All Island  28 August 2021 05:15,489,All Island  28 August 2021 05:30,487,All Island  28 August 2021 05:45,493,All Island  28 August 2021 06:00,492,All Island  28 August 2021 06:15,472,All Island  28 August 2021 06:30,469,All Island  28 August 2021 06:45,468,All Island  28 August 2021 07:00,472,All Island  28 August 2021 07:15,476,All Island  28 August 2021 07:30,482,All Island  28 August 2021 07:45,473,All Island  28 August 2021 08:00,465,All Island  28 August 2021 08:15,463,All Island  28 August 2021 08:30,467,All Island  28 August 2021 08:45,470,All Island  28 August 2021 09:00,460,All Island  28 August 2021 09:15,461,All Island  28 August 2021 09:30,463,All Island  28 August 2021 09:45,472,All Island  28 August 2021 10:00,478,All Island  28 August 2021 10:15,475,All Island  28 August 2021 10:30,475,All Island  28 August 2021 10:45,473,All Island  28 August 2021 11:00,459,All Island  28 August 2021 11:15,462,All Island  28 August 2021 11:30,445,All Island  28 August 2021 11:45,438,All Island  28 August 2021 12:00,433,All Island  28 August 2021 12:15,435,All Island  28 August 2021 12:30,429,All Island  28 August 2021 12:45,424,All Island  28 August 2021 13:00,430,All Island  28 August 2021 13:15,430,All Island  28 August 2021 13:30,431,All Island  28 August 2021 13:45,429,All Island  28 August 2021 14:00,419,All Island  28 August 2021 14:15,418,All Island  28 August 2021 14:30,416,All Island  28 August 2021 14:45,421,All Island  28 August 2021 15:00,411,All Island  28 August 2021 15:15,424,All Island  28 August 2021 15:30,430,All Island  28 August 2021 15:45,429,All Island  28 August 2021 16:00,424,All Island  28 August 2021 16:15,423,All Island  28 August 2021 16:30,416,All Island  28 August 2021 16:45,422,All Island  28 August 2021 17:00,425,All Island  28 August 2021 17:15,439,All Island  28 August 2021 17:30,439,All Island  28 August 2021 17:45,440,All Island  28 August 2021 18:00,440,All Island  28 August 2021 18:15,426,All Island  28 August 2021 18:30,439,All Island  28 August 2021 18:45,429,All Island  28 August 2021 19:00,437,All Island  28 August 2021 19:15,440,All Island  28 August 2021 19:30,436,All Island  28 August 2021 19:45,441,All Island  28 August 2021 20:00,434,All Island  28 August 2021 20:15,446,All Island  28 August 2021 20:30,434,All Island  28 August 2021 20:45,447,All Island  28 August 2021 21:00,443,All Island  28 August 2021 21:15,456,All Island  28 August 2021 21:30,447,All Island  28 August 2021 21:45,448,All Island  28 August 2021 22:00,447,All Island  28 August 2021 22:15,426,All Island  28 August 2021 22:30,418,All Island  28 August 2021 22:45,433,All Island  28 August 2021 23:00,438,All Island  28 August 2021 23:15,440,All Island  28 August 2021 23:30,434,All Island  28 August 2021 23:45,434,All Island
```

Example of the first 3 rows and columns would be:

```
28 August 2021 00:00  |  470  |  All Island
28 August 2021 00:15  |  471  |  All Island
28 August 2021 00:30  |  471  |  All Island
```

So the output I would like to achieve is a table like this

```
      DATE & TIME     |  CO2 INTENSITY (gCO2/kWh)  |  REGION
-----------------------------------------------------------------
28 August 2021 00:00  |          470               |  All Island
28 August 2021 00:15  |          471               |  All Island
28 August 2021 00:30  |          471               |  All Island
```

I have tried a verity of split strings and bulk imports and have not managed it. e.g.

```
 --;with CTE(raw) as 
 --(
 ----select @Data as raw
 --select replace(replace(replace(replace(@Data ,' ','-'),' ','-'),' 
 ','- 
 '),' ','-')
 --   )
 --select * from CTE

-- write to file first and then import e.g.
--BULK INSERT [AutoData].[dbo].[Eirgrid_Co2Data]
--FROM 'C:\TempData\FileName.csv'
--WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');

 -- Tried to read it as JSON and XML!
 --select * from OPENJSON(@Data)
 select @Data

 -- splitting!
 --  SELECT value  
 --FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Data, ',')
 ----FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Data, '  ')  'split of double space!
 --WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Comment: Your "data" looks mangle to me and that is confusing. If you un-mangle it, that will encourage others to help. Referring to a string and then to "rows" is equally confusing. Context would help. A script that contains DDL, sample data, and desired output based on that sample data would greatly help.

Comment: This really needs a lot more detail. Do you know the columns ahead of time ie can remove them from the data? Or do you need to dynamically create the table based on the data? If so what it the criteria for determining the end of columns and start of data? There's no line break before the first "data" row or line breaks to indicate a new row. How is anyone supposed to approach this with any confidence?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I have updated the question, anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the line delimiter is 2 spaces.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't make it easy to split on 2 spaces.  It also appears there is some outlier data, i.e. ItemNumber=7 where there is an actual carriage return.  To brute force get'er done this replaces the 2 spaces (and 1 space with 1 carriage return) with a tilde '~' and then uses an ordinal splitter to split on the tilde.

Ordinal splitter [described here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

query

```
declare @string         nvarchar(max)=N'DATE & TIME, CO2 INTENSITY (gCO2/kWh), REGION  27 August 2021 00:00,465,All Island  27 August 2021 00:15,459,All Island  27 August
2021 00:30,463,All Island  27 August 2021 00:45,464,All Island  27
August 2021 01:00,461,All Island  27 August 2021 01:15,465,All Island 
27 August 2021 01:30,466,All Island  27 August 2021 01:45,470,All
Island  27 August 2021 02:00,466,All Island';


select *
from dbo.DelimitedSPlit8K_LEAD(replace(replace(@string, ' 
','~'), '  ','~'), '~') dl;
```

```
ItemNumber  Item
1           DATE & TIME, CO2 INTENSITY (gCO2/kWh), REGION
2           27 August 2021 00:00,465,All Island
3           27 August 2021 00:15,459,All Island
4           27 August  2021 00:30,463,All Island
5           27 August 2021 00:45,464,All Island
6           27  August 2021 01:00,461,All Island
7           27 August 2021 01:15,465,All Island
8           27 August 2021 01:30,466,All Island
9           27 August 2021 01:45,470,All  Island
10          27 August 2021 02:00,466,All Island
```

Comment: Thanks @SteveC much appreciated, I have updated my question to show more detail on what I am looking for.

Answer (score -3):

The method I've used for years is found here [tally table solution](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

At the end is the function for the CTE varchar version. The above link also has a nvarchar version if needed.

One note, your data doesn't seem to have consistent delimiters so you will likely need to use the below multiple times.

As an example, using the first row of your data above:

```
DECLARE @Rowdata Varchar(100) = '27 August 2021 02:25,465,All Island' ;

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@Rowdata,',')
```

Yields the result set of:

*ItemNumber*    **Item**

*1*             **27 August 2021 02:25**

*2*             **465**

*3*             **All Island**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Comment: A answer needs to contain the full answer to the question. Not a link to an external resource.